# How to use all neon units efficiently in multi-core processor with neon intrinsics

Tags: neon

Neon intinsics leave the allocation of registers to the compiler,so we don't need to care about it.But I want to know in the multi-core processor(My processor is zynq,has two arm-cortex-A9 cores, two neon units),does compiler know how to use all neon units efficiently?Or is there anything I need to do to make sure compiler can use all neon units?

I think in the multi-core processor,if we can use all neon units,we may get better performance gain.Dose anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense - the NEON unit is still part of the CPU core. Unless you're effectively asking "how can I write multi-threaded code to run on both cores?", but without more specifics that's going to fall under "too broad".

Comment: Thanks!It's my mistake.Do you mean which NEON unit we use is determinded by which CPU core we use?

Comment: Yes, regardless of how tightly integrated it is into the rest of the pipeline (from "not very" on Cortex-A8 to "inseparably" on some current cores), it's still as much a part of the CPU core as the integer ALU or any other block. I'd hope that you could see the folly in asking "Or is there anything I need to do to make sure compiler can use all register files/instruction decoders/load-store units?" - it's no different for the FPU, whether it's VFP-only or a full NEON vector pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

NEON is a function unit in the shader core, just SSE for x86, and as such behaves like any of the "normal" integer or floating point instructions.

The compiler can handle using the units within a single core automatically, but using multiple NEON units in multiple cores will require explicit application logic to split the work over multiple threads.